# Firewall pattern with Symfony

Tags: symfony, security, design-patterns, firewall

I have an API with Oauth2 authentication developed with Symfony framework. I use the security mechanism provided by Symfony and my security.yml is as follows :

```
security:
    ...
    register:
        pattern: ^/users
        methods: [POST]
    ...
    api:
        pattern: ^/
        fos_oauth: true
        stateless: true
```

As you can see, a new user is registered by the POST request /users. But my problem is that another POST request with URL like /users/xxxx matches the rule too. Is it possible to reject URLs with the same root ? Thanks for help.

Comment: add `$` sign at the end, `pattern: ^/users$`

Comment: It works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: accept my answer please, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `$` sign at the end, pattern: `^/users$` should work.